# Can we overlap UI elements in watchOS?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2, watchos-3, watch-notification

How can I design table view row like:
[image]

I can't overlap UI elements in storyboard so is there any way to design table row like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overlap objects in storyboard, but you can get creative with groups. You can place your UI elements into a group (or a group within a group) and then set the background image of the group(s) to either be a static image or animate through a set of images which may give the appearance of overlapping objects. Hope this helps!